# Java Collections Framework's sorting algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm, collections

I'm trying to understand how Java Collections Framework sorts its collections by default and I got confused, because I read all the collections are being sorted using merge sort. But as I took a look at Array class I saw this: «Implementors should feel free to substitute other algorithms, so long as the specification itself is adhered to. (For example, the algorithm used bysort(Object[]) does not have to be a mergesort, but it does have to be stable.)» Which means it also uses other sorting algorithms. So how exactly are the collections being sorted?

Comment: Unless you are implementing Arrays class yourself, it is using merge sort.  Also, Arrays is not the same as Collections

Comment: `Collections.sort` delegates to `Arrays.sort`, which uses [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code to sort collections is delivered with the JRE/JDK.

Anyone who *implements* the JRE/JDK can choose to implement it in any way he wants, as long as it's conforming (i.e. it actually sorts the collection correctly and the sorting is stable).

*Some* implementations might choose merge-sort, others might choose something else. No specific implementation is required.